# Sampling two values with the proximity dependency

Tags: sampling

Given the $X{\sim}\mathsf{LogNorm}(\mu,\sigma)$ (or any other well-defined non-symmetric distribution), how one would sample two values, such as the first value $X_1$ is sampled from the $X$ and the $X_2$ is sampled from some sort of a mixed/composition distribution which 1) decreases when moving from $X_1$ (so $X_1$ is the mode of this distribution); 2) influenced by asymmetry defined by initial distribution $X$.

In other words:

1. The probability of having $X_2$ far away from $X_1$ decreases with the distance;
2. If $X_1$ is high (bigger than mode) then $P(X_2 > X_1) < P(X_2 < X_1)$
3. If $X_1$ is low (lower than mode) then $P(X_2 > X_1) > P(X_2 < X_1)$

Visually, it can be imagined like a hill: if $X_1$ is close to the top, there is a low chance for $X_2$ to be higher. Otherwise, if $X_1$ is in the lowlands, then there is a higher chance for $X_2$ to be higher.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not look well defined, but one option might be to sample $A$, then take two samples of $X$.  If $|X_1-X_2| < A$ then you are done; if not then start again.  There is a question as to whether you would want to resample $A$, or just $X_1$ and $X_2$, or even just $X_2$ - it depends on what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. In general, I want to know if we can derive the PDF/CDF for $X_2$ if $X_1$ is already sampled and $A$ is normally distributed. The trick here is that for high values of $X_1$ the $P(X_2 > X_1) < P(X_2 < X_1)$.

Comment: maybe, my other [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/632637/mix-convolution-of-log-normal-and-normal-distributions-for-the-proximity-depe) can give a little of the context (I am struggling to correctly formulate the mathematical problem)

Comment: It *sounds* like you wish to sample from a truncated bivariate distribution.  The general setting is a bivariate random variable $X$ and the truncation region is $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid |x-y|\lt a\}.$ In some cases you will be able to compute one of the marginal distributions and the conditional distribution of the other and thereby accomplish the sampling in two steps.  @Henry's proposal is a form of rejection sampling: that will work fine for large $a,$ but for smaller $a$ a better initial proposal would be desirable. Are your two values of $X$ independent or not?

Comment: @whuber, generally speaking, I want them to be **dependent** in the following way: $X_1$ is sampled randomly from the distribution $X$. $X_2$ is then sampled in a way that 1) it follows the base distribution $X$; 2) the probability for $X_2$ to be far away from $X_1$ decreases with the distance. Also, as I've mentioned above: *for a high value of $X_1$ probability of $X_2 > X_1$ would be less than the probability of $X_2 < X_1$*

Comment: "Decreases with the distance" needs to be quantified.  Otherwise, no progress can be made.  Generally, your two requirements cannot simultaneously be fulfilled.

Comment: @whuber, it is quantified in the original post: decreases as normal PDF. The PDF for $X_1$ is $f_X$, while the PDF for $X_2$ should be some sort of a product $f_X*g_Y$ where $Y{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(X_1,std\_dev)$

Comment: What you write here in the comments and what you write in the post are different: sampling $a$ has nothing to do with the distribution of $(X_1,X_2).$  Please edit the post to clarify it.

Comment: @whuber, ok I've added the details from the discussion to the main post, hope it helps.

Comment: That's clear, thank you: but the question now answers itself.  You sample $X_1$ according to the first distribution and then sample $X_2$ according to the second distribution (which is completely determined from your sample of $X_1$).

Comment: @whuber, the question is "how determined"? Because it shouldn't be symmetric (like normal noise with the mean $X_1$), but rather skewed to the left or the right depending on the position of $X_1$. That is why I suggested a product of two PDFs, but I am not sure if it is a correct approach

Comment: That sounds like an inherent contradiction, because you explicitly state you want the conditional distribution of $X_2$ to be Normal.  This makes it hard to know what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @whuber, I rather state that $X_2$ should be sampled from a mix between lognormal (i.e. asymmetrical distribution) and normal (i.e. symmetrical). There are two conditions: 1)  sample far from $X_1$ is less probable; 2) asymmetry of initial PDF must influence

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what you write: your expression explicitly states $X_2$ has a Normal distribution conditional on $X_1.$

Comment: @whuber, quote from the post: *"$X_2$ is sampled from some sort of a mixed distribution <...>"*. I do not define it, I simply describe its desirable properties: 1) fall off when moving from $X_1$; 2) keeps asymmetry defined by initial distribution $X$

Comment: Then you had better remove "$Y{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(X_1,std\_dev),$" which contradicts that.

Comment: @whuber, I've never said that $X_2$ is sampled from the normal $Y$; definition of $Y$ was given to highlight the first desirable property, which is *decreasing then moving from $X_1$*. I changed the wording in the post, even if I don't believe it will change the whole situation with the lack of answers.

Comment: At this point you seem to describe a property of independent samples from any unimodal distribution.  Because you are struggling to articulate your question, please consider telling us about the actual application you would like to address, rather than attempting to formulate your question abstractly.

Comment: @whuber, [here it is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/632637/385623)